# Dart stream operator equivalent of RxJS tap

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

I'm doing my first streams in dart and I would like to print some of my values after observable `operators` before they make it to the `listen`, much like `tap` in RxJS. Is this possible? I can't find it in RxDart either.

For example:

```
final pulseStream = field.control.valueChanges
    .where((dynamic val) => (val as String).length < 20)
    .tap(print)
    .where((dynamic val) => (val as String).isNotEmpty)
    .tap(print)
    .where((dynamic val) => pulseController != null)
    .tap(print)
    .where((dynamic val) => !pulseController.isAnimating);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is `doX` operator:

```dart
RxDart                             |  RxJS
------------------------
doOnData(print)                    | tap(console.log) or tap({ next: console.log })
doOnError((e, s) => print(e))      | tap({ error: console.log })
doOnDone(() => print('done'))      | tap({ complete: () => console.log('complete') })
```